# How do I disable a specific wifi network through terminal?

Tags: terminal, wifi, internet

Is there a way to disable a specific wifi network in Terminal? I'd like to disable my home wifi connection for reasons outlined here: [Reclaim Your Life After Work by Disabling Internet Access for Smartphones](http://lifehacker.com/5877112/reclaim-your-life-after-work-by-disabling-internet-access-for-smartphones)

My housemates would like to keep wifi so I can't just turn it off.

I've disable some websites using terminal as outlined here [Block Access to Websites on a Mac by Modifying /etc/hosts](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/19/block-access-to-specified-sites-by-modifying-etchosts/)

But I don't want to block everything so I can still use wifi at work, a library or coffee shop. Is there any way to block a specific network? I also don't want it to show up or be usable in the Network Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

OS X and iOS all save known networks, so just forget that network and tell your computer to not ask to join networks.

The steps vary, but you should be able to open help from the Finder and search for "Choose preferred Wi-Fi networks" and it will guide you to the advanced settings for networking so you can delete any networks you don't want to join again. If you have many, you might delete them all and start fresh by only joining networks you intend to use for work purposes.

If you want to go a step further, delete the network password from your Keychain or change the password on the router and your mac won't re-join that network ever.

Enjoy your break from the home network.

p.s. deleting this from terminal isn't something I know how to do, so sorry if you really wanted to learn how to script things, but this seems like something you could accomplish in 3 minutes or less without complicating things in terminal.